# add python interpreter to an existing project in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, interpreter, pythoninterpreter

I have a python project on 2 different computers linked with GitHub so that I can open the project on both computers. Until now, it worked, but now I have this problem : I can't run the project on my laptop because of a missing python interpreter (see the image down below). I searched for solutions to solve this, but none of them worked.

when I click on the drop-down list showing the python interpreters I can use, none of them works (see the second image down below) because the project I'm working on is in the cloud, and all the interpreters are on my hard drive.

So my question is : how add python interpreter to this existing project ?

[image]
[image]